# How to push notification with socket service in background when application is closed in ionic 4?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, socket.io, ionic4

I must push notification from my own socket side server when the application is closed or application is in the background. Where do I need to write a typescript code in my project to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The push notifications require **registration** between your mobile device (the app) and the Push Notification services (Google GCM/FCM or Apple APNS).

Registering your application via a unique identifier will allow your application to receive notifications (actually the OS will handle them) anytime, even if the application is closed, in background or foreground.

If you want to send **data** (represented as notifications) from your server via sockets you should consider implementing a background handler to listen for that data. If the app is closed, you may need to use a Plugin (native code required) to wake up your app and listen for changes.

Have a look [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/socket-io-and-background-and-foreground/122863) to understand better how the Ionic Apps are working in background with Sockets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have made an application on my server side to send data from socket, I can use application in background mode but i can not send notification when it is in background, i wanna find a way to sending push notification with my own service.

Comment: Unfortunately Ionic is providing only couple events related to moving the application in background or resuming. You can develop your own native plugin (android and iOS) to handle the background state. You can find the events [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) and maybe use them as a workaround. I never tried with Ionic but you can have a look into the Push Notifications Browser API (not supported by Safari yet - iOS) that will allow you a slightly different approach. Good luck!